# Django "500 internal server error" on login attempt in production

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache2

I'm new to django and web design in general but I have a small apache2 webserver running on a raspberry pi, I have successfuly set up the server to work with django 2.2 and I can access the site via a dataplicity wormhole and the site will load correctly. However, when I attempt to login through dataplicity hosted site (admin page or the website) I get an "500- internal server error".

There is nothing in the apache error log and if I run the server via `python manage.py runserver` login works as expected only when running it through apache do I get the problem.

This is my apache2.conf:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/pi/pi_site/pi_website/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /home/pi/pi_site/myvenv
WSGIPythonPath /home/pi/pi_site

<Directory /home/pi/pi_site/pi_website>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/pi/pi_site/static/

<Directory /home/pi/pi_site/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

And my settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '*******'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [".dataplicity.io", "127.0.0.1"]


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main_site',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pi_website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pi_website.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-uk'

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

**Edit**:
I've attempted setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` but this didn't effect the 500 message. I also tried deleting and re-migrating the database creating a new superuser but again with no impact

**Edit- 2**:
I only get the 500 message on login and only with correct credencials, if I use the wrong login/password the page responds correctly

Comment: So, you're able to login to your site via local host and dataplicity, but not on a different host? Is that correct? If that is the case, you may need to add the different host to your ALLOWED_HOSTS in your settings.py file.

Comment: @rob no I can login with 127.0.0.1:8000 when I run `python manage.py runserver` but when I attempt to login when its running off dataplicity/apache I get the 500 error

Comment: try `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` just to try and eliminate causes

Comment: @PercivalRapha no, I just got the same 500 error after trying to log in

Comment: To clarify, are there pages that don't require login that are working OK, and it's just a problem logging in?  Also, your settings have `DEBUG = True` so most 500 errors would show some debug info.  I guess you are not seeing any?

Comment: @MarkBailey yes that's all correct only a login issue and the 500 page has no other information other then "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check file permissions for your database file.  Maybe Apache doesn't have permission to write to it.  That would allow pages where only a read is needed, but a login needs to write to the database.  When running it though runserver it will access that file as your user, so permissions could be OK for that.